# Syntax Error with Django, WSGI, and Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am getting a weird error while trying to run my Django site under Apache using mod_wsgi. I have been working on this for hours to no avail.

FYI: I am also using Mezzanine.

Log:

```
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30] mod_wsgi (pid=15554): Target WSGI script '/opt/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30] mod_wsgi (pid=15554): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]   File "/opt/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]     from django.utils.version import get_version
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 7, in <module>
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]     from django.utils.lru_cache import lru_cache
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 28
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]      fasttypes = {int, str, frozenset, type(None)},
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]                      ^
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

httpd.conf for mysite (there are others on the server)

```
# Redirects all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerName test-mysite
    #ServerAlias test-mysite mysite.com mysite
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite test-mysite.com test-mysite

    DocumentRoot /opt/mysite

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:443>
    #ServerName test-mysite.com
    #ServerAlias test-mysite
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite test-mysite.com test-mysite
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/ssl_mysite_error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/ssl_mysite_request_log \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    TransferLog /var/log/httpd/ssl_mysite_access_log
    LogLevel warn

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

    <Directory /opt/mysite/mysite>
        Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/othersite_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/othersite.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

`httpd -V` output:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 12 2016 07:03:49
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 28
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]      fasttypes = {int, str, frozenset, type(None)},
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]                      ^
[Fri Oct 14 23:48:13 2016] [error] [client 128.187.3.30]  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python 2.6 doesn't support `set` syntax `{....}`

You may [use a version of Django that supports Python 2.6](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-a-version-of-Django-to-use-with-python-2-6) but make sure it also supports `Mezzanine`
OR 
Update your Python installation to `2.7`